# Conditional probability and joint probability

Tags: probability

This is trivial,

Regarding probability and random variables. Are the following probabilities equivalent or similar?

$P(A=a \mid B=b)$  Conditional probability

$P(A=a,B=b)$  Joint probability

If not, what do they both mean?

Comment: I would say. http://sites.nicholas.duke.edu/statsreview/probability/jmc/

Comment: @georg Exactly the clarity I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are very different. The conditional probability is the probability that $A$ occurs given that you know that $B$ occurs.  If, for example $A=B$ then this is $1$.  The joint probability is the probability that both occur.  If for example $A=B$ then this is $P(A)$.

To give a concrete example, consider one toss of a fair die.  Let $A$ denote the event "you throw a $2$", let $B$ be the event "you throw less than a $4$.

Then the Conditional Probability $P(A|B)$ is the probability that you have thrown a $2$ *Given that* you know you have thrown less than a $4$.  That value is $\frac 13$.

The joint Probability is the probability that both occur, which is $\frac 16$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A=a\mid B=b)$ is the condition probability that random variable $A$ has value $a$ when it is given that variable $B$ has value $b$

$P(A=a, B=b)$ is the joint probability that random variable $A$ has value $a$ and that random variable $B$ has value $b$

These are related as follows:  $$P(A=a,B=b)= P(B=b)\;P(A=a\mid B=b)$$